# Get all Posts If has same custom field values in Posts

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field

I am trying to get a list of posts if has same zipcode values. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
<?php
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type'=> array('service'),
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'meta_query' => array( array(
   'key'=> 'zipcode',
   'value'=> ','.$zip.',',
   'compare'=> 'LIKE'
) )
 ));                 
    ?>      

    <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();  ?>

<h3><?php the_title(); ?> </h3>

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <?php else: ?>
    No results found.
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What does the above code do? Is it working? And what do the full values in `zipcode` look like? Can you reformat your code so it's easier to read? Indenting correctly should be enough

Comment: @TomJNowell `zipcode` are numbers for example `12345`. If posts have value `12345` in the custom field. then it should display all posts which have the `12345` value. The above code is working fine but displays only one post.

Comment: Are those metavalues only zipcodes? Your code block implies it's actually a comma separated list e.g. 12346,67890,etc...

Answer (score 2):

Following code will be proper for the meta query.

```
  $query_args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'service',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query'  => array(
            array(
                'value'   => $zip,
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
                'key'     => 'zipcode',
            ),
        )
    );
   $query = new WP_Query($query_args);
   <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) :while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();  ?>
       <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
   <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
   <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
   <?php else: ?>
      No results found.
   <?php endif; ?>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> This code may help you to get perfect results.

```
<?php
$query_args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'service',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query'  => array(
        array(
           'key'=> 'zipcode',
           'value'=> $zip,
           'type' => 'numeric',
           'compare'=> '=',
        ),
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query($query_args);
if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();  ?>
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
else: ?>
    <h3>No results found.</h3>
<?php endif; ?>
```